# Access non-friends profile updates using php

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-apps

Is it possible to access profile updates of a facebook user who is not in your(application authorizer) friend list or like-list?

For example:
http://www.facebook.com/zuck
or
http://www.facebook.com/mashable

Is it possible using facebook api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    require 'src/facebook.php';
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
      'appId'  => 'xxx',
      'secret' => 'xxx',
    ));
    $username = isset($_GET['username'])?$_GET['username']:"johnbevere.page";
    $profile = $facebook->api('/'.$username.'/posts');
?>

<br/><br/><img src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?=$username?>/picture">

<?php
    foreach( $profile['data'] as $data ){
        if($data['message']){
            echo $data['message']."<br><hr><br>";
        }else{
            echo $data['story']."<br><hr><br>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Success:

1. Page updates
2. User timeline Activity Log

Failed:

1. User timeline Feed

**It is not possible to scrap the public feed of random profile using facebook API**

Answer (score 0):

It depends on their privacy settings